# Returning a quick statistical info for a cell as a comment

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary, scripting

I have a long list of data on an excel table. This data includes detail information of each order in several rows. There is a column shows the status of each row. Also, I have a dashboard which just lists out the order names. I want the users to be able to see a short statistical info of each book as a comment or when they mouse over the cell, if possible or as a cell data. The info could be something like underneath sample in 3 or 4 row. (The number of items is the count of rows with the same status)

> 5 issued item
>    3 shortage items
>    2 Done items
>    X other

If you just give me the general idea it would be great.
I think I have to use a collection procedure, something like "scripting dictionary" but I have no experience using them. I know how to do that by putting a case statement after if clause inside a loop, but I am looking for a smarter way. you can find some pictures and a sample data below: [sample](https://1drv.ms/x/s!ArGi1KRQ5iItgYwUIlw2-u6kMhGlVQ) [pictures](https://s23.postimg.org/4vrbe361n/order_comment_info.jpg)

Comment: I'm not sure if the picture in your link is small enough, could you make it tinier please?

Comment: Sadly not on the points front, but I won't down vote you, and I'll tell you why your question is not great, and why I'll flag it to be closed.  You're looking to return info based on mouse position(as far as i can tell this is your main question), but you don't mention this in the title.  You include no code and show no research effort.  On the positive side, the answer is that there is no mouse position/ hover event in vba (kinda not so positive really).  And you could use a dictionary I guess... but as part of a much bigger section of code.  I'm sorry you need to make this question better

Comment: Hi, Thanks, Actually I am not looking for a mouse over reaction. I just want a smooth reply to the users. As I mentioned in my post, even a cell value result (something that can I put it in a cell) is ok. By the way I dont know waht the reputation stands for, Just it dosen't let me to give positive feedback to the others. It is why I asked for it. otherwise I am not a professional developer. Thanks anyway. and If you found it ok to give a negative point. No worry go ahead. Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, I came to this answer from one of friends in MrExcel froum. Hope you find it usefull. 
The just difference is, I was looking for a momentum reply just for an active cell, but this code, provide all the information for all the order names as a comment. but it is very easy to adjust!

```
Sub UpdateComments()
Dim c As Variant, strComment As String
Dim intISSUED As Integer, intSHORTAGE As Integer
Dim tblDATA As ListObject, tblDASH As ListObject
Set tblDATA = Application.Range("TBL.data").ListObject 'adjust Table Name
Set tblDASH = Application.Range("TBL.dash").ListObject 'adjust Table Name
For Each c In tblDASH.ListColumns("W/B").DataBodyRange
    strComment = ""
    intISSUED = Application.CountIfs(tblDATA.ListColumns("Work Book").DataBodyRange, c, tblDATA.ListColumns("Stage").DataBodyRange, "Issued")
    strComment = strComment & Chr(10) & "Issued: " & intISSUED
    intSHORTAGE = Application.CountIfs(tblDATA.ListColumns("Work Book").DataBodyRange, c,tblDATA.ListColumns("Stage").DataBodyRange, "Shortage")
    strComment = strComment & Chr(10) & "Shortage: " & intSHORTAGE
    '  ADDITIONAL 'STAGES' HERE
    '  OR put 'stages' in array to condense code
    With Sheets(tblDASH.Parent.Name).Range(c.Address)
        If .Comment Is Nothing Then
            .AddComment
            .Comment.Visible = False
        End If
        .Comment.Text Text:=Mid(strComment, 2)
    End With
Next c
End Sub
```